# Where do some numbers in finance papers which seem to appear out of nowhere come from?

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, papers

On p. 1671 in the paper [Kempf/Manconi/Spalt (2017, RfS), *Distracted shareholders and corporate actions*](https://doi.org/10.1093/rfs/hhw082) it says (I think it is in the context of a log regression):

> Those effects are economically meaningful. A one-standard deviation change in distraction leads to 19% (=−2.671×0.07) fewer active conference call participants and 6% (=−0.834×0.07) fewer proposals by institutions.

Where does the 0.07 come from? I searched throughout the document, and could only find it as value of $R^2$. It seems to appear out of nowhere. Some people suggest that it is p-value, which does not make sense for me.